# Make changes in UI work in background (with ProgressDialog)?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app where in one of the activity different views are added into a ViewGroup, this process takes a while starting up so I wanted to run a progress Dialog in foreground while the UI could setUp in background .

**What I have Tried**

I tried using

1.**AsyncTask** but it gave Exceptions .
2. while using threads and **runnable()** I am getting **InvocationTargetException**.

I wanted to know what could be the best possible approach to this?

Comment: AsyncTask is a good choice. If you have errors, you should fix them. And if you don't like this rude answer, you might want to improve your question ;)

Comment: AsyncTask dont allow UI changes in doInBackground()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make UI changes from a background task.

If you use an `AsyncTask`, you can only update the UI from the `onPostExecute()` or `onProgressUpdate()` methods.

The other option is to use a `Handler`, which (amongst others) can execute `Runnable`s on the main thread.

Edit:
The Handler has to be instantiated on the main thread. From any thread, you could use `post(Runnable)` or `sendMessage(Message)` and various variations of them. For `sendMessage()` you would need to override `handleMessage(Message)`.

Comment: Using Handler it is working correctly but I am not able to run ProgressDialog in foreground any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you insert some of your code? It would help a lot determining the cause of the problem.

But you need to know that you can't change the UI from a background thread. It will give you an exception. 
What you can do is write an `AsyncTask`, which initializes the objects and assigns values to them in its `doInBackground` method and then modifies the UI thread in its `onPostExecute` method.

It would look something like this:

```
private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
   //show progress dialog
  }

  @Override
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
  {
    //init objects, and do stuff with them
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
  {
    //make changes to UI thread 
    //close progress dialog
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Juste keep your AsyncTask and update UI in onPostExecute instead to do it in doInBackground.

Comment: It works but I want to show a progressdialog in foreground which doesnot appear!!

Comment: I think we need more info to resolve your issue. Do you have an extract of the code you use? Could you give us the stack of the exception you get when you use the AsyncTask solution?